# error ora-00922: missing or invalid operation on trigger

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I was trying to set up a simple trigger when something is deleted from enrolls it also deletes from scores and student tables. I feel like I have set everything up properly, but I keep getting this error: error ora-00922: missing or invalid operation. I have done some research into the error, but I am not getting anywhere with. I am doing this in sql developer. I am semi new to sql so any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is below:

```
delimiter //
create or replace TRIGGER enrolls_trigger

AFTER DELETE ON ENROLLS

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DELETE FROM scores

WHERE scores.sid= old.sid

AND scores.term = old.term AND scores.lineno = old.lineno

AND scores.compname = old.compname AND scores.points = old.points;

DELETE FROM students

WHERE students.sid = old.sid;

END//
```

Comment: What is `delimiter //`? Get rid of that and replace the `//` at the end with a `;` Also it's worth getting into the habit of formatting your code for readability.

Comment: Refer to `old.column_name`  with a colon in the beginning. i.e.  `:old.column_name`

Comment: consider @littlefoot's approach - no need to have the trigger if that's your goal, to clean up related records

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a bit off. To reference the previous value of a DML transaction, you use :old.

```
-- delimiter
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER enrolls_trigger AFTER
    DELETE ON enrolls
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM scores
    WHERE
        scores.sid =:old.sid
        AND scores.term =:old.term
        AND scores.lineno =:old.lineno
        AND scores.compname =:old.compname
        AND scores.points =:old.points;

    DELETE FROM students
    WHERE
        students.sid =:old.sid;

END;
--delimiter
```

Also, if you're using SQL Developer, you'll want to have an ';' after your END keyword on the trigger body.

[Trigger Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374)

For better help going forward, include your TABLE DDL. I created these for ease of use.

```
CREATE TABLE enrolls (
    sid        INTEGER,
    term       INTEGER,
    lineno     INTEGER,
    compname   VARCHAR2(10),
    points     INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE scores (
    sid        INTEGER,
    term       INTEGER,
    compname   VARCHAR2(10),
    points     INTEGER,
    lineno     INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE students (
    sid   INTEGER
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! What you said fixed a lot. My only issue now is that I am getting bad bind errors for :old.compname and :old.points. Any reason you could think of for what is causing that? I compiled it without those two and it compiled fine so its just those two that are messing up.

Comment: Yes they are which is why I am really unsure why I am getting the error for them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest another approach - foreign key constraints created with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option. Have a look at the following example.

Thanks to Jeff who provided CREATE TABLE statements which I've slightly modified, i.e. added only necessary constraints. Note that I've chosen only the SID column to be a foreign key from the SCORES table to ENROLLS. BTW, what's the point in repeating that many columns in the SCORES table? I'd suggest you to keep only the foreign key constraint column (such as SID), and omit the others.

Finally, here we go: Create tables:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE enrolls (
  2      sid        INTEGER constraint pk_en primary key,
  3      term       INTEGER,
  4      lineno     INTEGER,
  5      compname   VARCHAR2(10),
  6      points     INTEGER
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE scores (
  2      sid        INTEGER,
  3      term       INTEGER,
  4      lineno     INTEGER,
  5      compname   VARCHAR2(10),
  6      points     INTEGER,
  7      constraint fk_sco_en foreign key (sid)
  8        references enrolls
  9        on delete cascade
 10  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE students (
  2      sid   INTEGER,
  3      constraint fk_stu_en foreign key (sid)
  4        references enrolls
  5        on delete cascade
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Insert sample data:

```
SQL> insert into enrolls  (sid, term) values (100, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into enrolls  (sid, term) values (200, 2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into scores   (sid, term) values (100, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into scores   (sid, term) values (200, 2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into students (sid)       values (100);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into students (sid)       values (200);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select * From students;

       SID
----------
       100
       200

SQL> select * From scores;

       SID       TERM     LINENO COMPNAME       POINTS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       100          1
       200          2

SQL> select * From enrolls;

       SID       TERM     LINENO COMPNAME       POINTS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       100          1
       200          2

SQL>
```

Now: if I delete a row from the ENROLLS table, Oracle will do the rest:

```
SQL> delete from enrolls where sid = 100;

1 row deleted.

SQL> select * From students;

       SID
----------
       200

SQL> select * From scores;

       SID       TERM     LINENO COMPNAME       POINTS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       200          2

SQL> select * From enrolls;

       SID       TERM     LINENO COMPNAME       POINTS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       200          2

SQL>
```

See? SID = 100 has been deleted from **all tables**, without any additional coding (i.e. no triggers needed).